# SQLCLR stored procedure fails to install

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes, sqlclr

I have created a stored procedure in Visual Studio (VS). When I attempt to install the procedure after successfully creating the assembly I get the error:

> CREATE PROCEDURE for sp_GetDistanceAndTime failed because T-SQL and CLR types for parameter "@Profile" do not match.

How do I get this to install? Are my parameters incorrect?

**C# code:**

```cs
public partial class StoredProcedures
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
    public static void SqlStoredProcedure1(SqlString Profile, SqlString StartPosition,
           SqlString Destination)
    {
        try
        {           
            SqlPipe sqlPipe = SqlContext.Pipe;
            string result;
            result = PTVRequest.InvokeService(Profile.ToString(),
                    StartPosition.ToString(), Destination.ToString());

            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

**SQL code:**

```sql
Create Procedure sp_GetDistanceAndTime(@Profile text, @StartPosition text,
 @Destination text)
AS 
External NAME GetPvt.StoredProcedures.SqlStoredProcedure1
go
```

Comment: For starters you do NOT want to use the text datatype. It has been deprecated in favor for varchar(max) since 2005. But do you REALLY need that much storage? Find a datatype that is appropriate. Also don't use the sp_ prefix. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: You might look at datatype mapping...seems the text datatype is an absolute not going to happen for CLR. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-types-net-framework/mapping-clr-parameter-data?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for correcting my sql it is working as expected now. Both comments where valuable.

Comment: SQLCLR is *NOT* meant to call web services from inside the database, eating up buffer memory and blocking execution. You gain *nothing* by putting the service call in there. Write a proper ETL script eg with SSIS or an external application. You can use SSIS's Script task or transformation if you want to put the call in an SSIS package

Answer (score 0):

1. Never use the `TEXT`, `NTEXT`, or `IMAGE` datatypes. Those have been deprecated for 13 years now, starting with the release of SQL Server 2005 which introduced the `MAX` datatypes to replace those old blob types.
2. The SQLCLR API only handles Unicode strings (UTF-16LE) and not 8-bit encodings. So, you cannot use `CHAR(1 - 8000)`, `VARCHAR(1 - 8000)`, or `VARCHAR(MAX)`. And I don't think it likes `NCHAR` either. Your choices are: `NCHAR(1 - 4000)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. Both of those map to both `SqlString` and `SqlChars`.
3. `SqlContext.Pipe.Send(string)` is equivalent to using `PRINT` in T-SQL. It is just a message that shows up in the "Messages" tab in SSMS. It is neither a return value nor an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

A quick example (fix sizes to your case, etc):

```
public static void SqlStoredProcedure1([SqlFacet(MaxSize=100)] string Profile,
[SqlFacet(MaxSize=200)] string StartPosition,
[SqlFacet(MaxSize=100)] string Destination)
```

And:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetDistanceAndTime
   @Profile nVARCHAR(100), @StartPosition nVARCHAR(200), @Destination nVARCHAR(100)
   AS EXTERNAL NAME GetPvt.StoredProcedures.SqlStoredProcedure1
```

See [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092(SQL.100).aspx) for details.